# parse absent attributes in xml

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml output that contains absent attributes for some of the child elements. How can I parse and insert them into my database? The upper element has attributes "latitude" and "longitude" while the second element does not contain these attributes
See an excerpt of the xml structure below:

```
<response .....
<listings bathroom_number="1" bedroom_number="0" datasource_name="FindaProperty.com" guid="g1-jNtMTMxADMzIjM=E" img_height="120" img_url="http://2.l.uk.nestoria.nestimg.com/1v0/2/1/1v021c995ea319948304290aa563f0478ddf67b99e.2.jpg" img_width="160" keywords="Furnished" latitude="51.54570" lister_name="Gowerlane" listing_type="let" location_accuracy="9" longitude="-0.20220" price="180" price_coldrent="0" price_currency="GBP" price_formatted="180 GBP per week" price_high="180" price_low="180" price_type="weekly" property_type="flat" summary="We are the professional landlords and not agents. with immediate access to..."  title="Kilburn High Road, Kilburn, NW6" />
<listings bathroom_number="" bedroom_number="0" datasource_name="PropertyIndex" guid="g1-TNtMDN5YDO3EQO==" img_height="120" img_url="http://1.l.uk.nestoria.nestimg.com/1vb/0/4/1vb04a1d2f88c68d0b1b3e44c32f8ee68f92b9ea6f.2.jpg" img_width="160" keywords="Garden, Refurbished, Reception" lister_name="Ashley Milton" listing_type="let" price="500" price_coldrent="0" price_currency="GBP" price_formatted="500 GBP per week" price_high="500" price_low="500" price_type="weekly" property_type="flat" summary="Refurbished two double bedroom garden flat set in a period building with..." title="Flat to rent, London, NW3 - Garden" updated_in_days="1128.5" />
</response>
```

Below is my php code for retrieving the xml data and inserting into database:

```
<?php

$url = ("http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?action=search_listings&centre_point=51.5424,-0.1734,2km&listing_type=rent&property_type=all&price_min=min&price_max=max&bedroom_min=0&bedroom_max=0&number_of_results=50&has_photo=1&page=4");

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$latitude=array(-42.23, 42.23);
$longitude=array(-122.23, 122.23);

//use '%F' since it is float  signed/unsigned
$nodesNegV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@latitude="%-F"]', $latitude[0]);
$nodesPosV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@latitude="%F"]', $latitude[1]);

if (!empty($nodesNegV)) 
{
 printf('Latitude "%F" found which is negeative', $latitude[0]);
}  
else if(!empty($nodesPosV))
{
 printf('Latitude "%F" found which is positivetive', $latitude[1]);
}
else
{
echo "nothing found";
}

$nodesNegV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@longitude="%-F"]', $longitude[0]);
$nodesPosV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@longitude="%F"]', $longitude[1]);

if (!empty($nodesNegV)) 
{
 printf('Longitude "%F" found which is negeative', $longitude[0]);
}  
else if(!empty($nodesPosV))
{
 printf('Longitude "%F" found which is positivetive', $longitude[1]);
}
else
{
echo "nothing found";
}

foreach ($xml->response->listings as $entry) {


echo $entry->attributes()->bathroom_number;
echo $entry->attributes()->bedroom_number;
echo $entry->attributes()->datasource_name;
echo $entry->attributes()->guid;
echo $entry->attributes()->img_url;
echo $entry->attributes()->keywords;
echo $entry->attributes()->latitude;
echo $entry->attributes()->lister_name;
echo $entry->attributes()->listing_type;
echo $entry->attributes()->longitude;
echo $entry->attributes()->price;
echo $entry->attributes()->price_type;
echo $entry->attributes()->property_type;
echo $entry->attributes()->summary;
echo $entry->attributes()->title;

// Process XML file
// Opens a connection to a PostgresSQL server
$connection = pg_connect("dbname=postgis user=postgres password=local");
$query = "INSERT INTO nestoriaphp(bathroom, bedroom, datasource, guid, image, keywords, latitude, lister, listype, longitude, price, pricetype, property_type, summary, title) VALUES ('" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->bathroom_number) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->bedroom_number) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->datasource_name) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->guid) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->img_url) ."', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->keywords) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->latitude) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->lister_name) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->listing_type) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->longitude) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->price) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->price_type) ."', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->property_type) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->summary) . "', '" . pg_escape_string($entry->attributes()->title) . "')";

$result = pg_query($query);

printf ("These values are inserted into the database - %s %s %s", $entry->attributes()->bathroom_number, $entry->attributes()->bedroom_number, $entry->attributes()->datasource_name, $entry->attributes()->guid, $entry->attributes()->img_url, $entry->attributes()->keywords, $entry->attributes()->latitude, $entry->attributes()->lister_name, $entry->attributes()->listing_type, $entry->attributes()->longitude, $entry->attributes()->price, $entry->attributes()->price_type, $entry->attributes()->property_type, $entry->attributes()->summary, $entry->attributes()->title);

}
pg_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sprintf which returns a string produced according to the formatting string format.

Since your latitdue/longitude could be signed/unsgined here is the solution

**EDIT** Each `%` can be followed by `+` or `-`, hence `%-F` for negative coordinates but keep `%F` for unsigned which is `42.23`

```
   $latitude=array(-42.23, 42.23);
   $longitude=array(-122.23, 122.23);

   //use '%F' since it is float  signed/unsigned
   $nodesNegV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@latitude="%-F"]', $latitude[0]);
   $nodesPosV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@latitude="%F"]', $latitude[1]);

    if (!empty($nodesNegV)) 
   {
     printf('Latitude "%-F" found which is negeative', $latitude[0]);
   }  
   else if(!empty($nodesPosV))
   {
     printf('Latitude "%F" found which is positivetive', $latitude[1]);
   }
  else
  {
    echo "nothing found";
  }
```

Use the same method for longitude.

Comment: Before iterating over your xml check for the names that you think may be absent coz this method requires prior knowledge of the name/attribute in order to set up the XPath `$xml->path(....)`

Comment: I keep getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\XAMMP\...\nestoriauk.php on line 10 And this is the line: $nodesNegV = $xml->xpath(sprintf('/response/listings[@latitude="%F"]', $latitude[0]);

Comment: Please see my edited code and let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: the signed negative latitude requires `%-F` instead of `%F`. I just edited my answer.Go check it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8737/discussion-between-ladiesman217-and-akinboj)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check each attribute for existense in the loaded xml.

This is why we must always validate an xml file against a valid xml schema document to tell that all the attributes exists in each element of the xml document.

I dont think there is any way to do this any other easy way.

Comment: And how do I do the validation in this situation?

Comment: i donr really know how to do this but think this will help http://etutorials.org/Server+Administration/upgrading+php+5/Chapter+5.+XML/5.11+Validating+Against+a+Schema/ . Also the xsd needs to be created first and then your code will validate your xml for all the attributes specified in the xsd.